# Why are there two wikis?

Tags: community, ubuntu-wiki

Why are there two wikis related to Ubuntu?
The first one is [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki) and the second one is [Ubuntu-wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/).
Both of them seem to be related to the community. Are the sites the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I can see, the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) is more professional and more officially maintained, with less community articles by just anyone and more articles created by official groups.

It's also a hub for official information about Ubuntu and the related teams (LoCo teams info, Governance & Membership, etc.)

On the other hand, the [CommunityHelpWiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki) is just that. It's a Community wiki intended for helping people with problems, as opposed to providing them with facts. It's also a bit larger, with tutorials being the main focus.

Comment: [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) holds various types of contents. For instance you can find personal pages where individuals present themselves - nothing professional or official with those. Also, I don't understand why you say that [help.ubuntu.com/community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki) does not provide facts. I downvoted your answer, since I think that Wilf's and muru's answer explains it better.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I didn't say that help.ubuntu.com/community doesn't provide *any* facts, I said "as **opposed** to providing them with facts." I was referring to the fact that it's more of a help the user out with problems and offering tutorials wiki than a wiki that provides just raw facts. Also, I said the Ubuntu Wiki is **more** professional and **more** officially maintained. I didn't say that is was *only* professional and official.

Comment: Well, there is room for interpreting it otherwise. ;) Admittedly there is room for improvement of how the Ubuntu web site is organized. As regards user documentation it's spread out over (at least) three places: 1. help.ubuntu.com (the official documentation, maintained by the documentation team, not a wiki), 2. help.ubuntu.com/community (the community help wiki which is not systematically monitored by any official body), and 3. wiki.ubuntu.com (which contains some user documentation pages, but whose principal purpose is something else).

Answer (score 5):

I think they are there to do different things - https://help.ubuntu.com/ has official and community documentation on how to use Ubuntu and do things with it - e.g. [using the launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-launcher-intro.html). The community section is maintained by the community, and has various guides on different things *(e.g [Radoen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) graphics and drivers, [Security](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security) etc.)*

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ seems to be more about [*'What is Ubuntu?'*](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu), as well as [how to contribute](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/) to Ubuntu (as well as [events](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/calendars/)) and the [current Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Answer (score 4):

They are for two distinct uses:

- Contributing to Ubuntu itself: http://wiki.ubuntu.com
- Helping users use Ubuntu: http://help.ubuntu.com/community